# sugarcrm 6.5.13 js bugs

Tags: php, centos, sugarcrm

I have installed a fresh copy of sugarcrm on centos 5 php v5.2.4 and i get javascript errors.

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

{ajaxStatus.s owStatus(SUGAR.language.get('app_strings','LBL_LOADING_PAGE'

style-...qXfmstw (line 6, col 14)
```

Above copied from firebug console. When I click on account tab i get lots more errors. Has anyone fixed these bugs?

```
uncaught exception: AjaxUI error parsing response
[Break On This Error]   

{SUGAR.themes.setModuleTabs(r.moduleList);}

uncaught exception: AjaxUI error parsing response
```

A window also pops up that has a title which reads: `An error has occured:` and the content displays `{"content":"`

Answer (score 0):

Are all the files correctly loading? Take a look at the network console and look out for errors while loading files. Could be that the file permissions are wrong and that ajax tries to load but receives 404s or 500s

Answer (score 0):

substituted /\h/ for /[ \t]/ (tab or space character) in jssource/Minifier.php as follows:

```
diff -c Minifier.php.orig Minifier.php
*** Minifier.php.orig
--- Minifier.php
***************
*** 155,161 ****

          $js = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $js);
          $this->input = str_replace("\r", "\n", $js);
!         $this->input = preg_replace('/\h/u', ' ', $this->input);


          $this->a = $this->getReal();
--- 155,161 ----

          $js = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $js);
          $this->input = str_replace("\r", "\n", $js);
!         $this->input = preg_replace('/[ \t]/u', ' ', $this->input);


          $this->a = $this->getReal();
```

Copy over original versions of all JavaScript files from a clean source code.

The following lines overwrote all JavaScript files with originals from the distribution. Any customizations, which would have been overwritten by the following:

```
cd ../SugarCE-Full-6.5.4
find . -name "*.js" -exec cp {} ../SugarCRM/{} \;
```

where SugarCRM is the directory of install, and SugarCE-Full-6.5.4 is the unpacked fresh version of SugarCRM.

Clean out all "minified" JavaScript from the cache. From the top level directory in our SugarCRM instance:

```
cd cache/ ; find . -name "*.js" -exec /bin/rm -f {} \;
```

This was to make sure SugarCRM recreated the minified versions in cache using the corrected Minify.php.